# Are recursive functions in Verilog synthesizable?

Tags: recursion, verilog, hdl, synthesis

Functions which do not contain any delay assignments are synthesizable, hence all synthesized functions are combinational in nature. Will the function still remain synthesizable if we have a recursive call?

Taking an example of Factorial function (automatic).
This functions is present in a state machine. Every time the state is activated, the function would return the value to a register.

Will this function synthesize?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, recursive function can be synthesizable, but only if the depth of recursion can be determined at compile time. That usually means the arguments to each top-level call to the function are constants. Like any other loop, a synthesis tool needs to have a fixed number of iterations to know exactly how much hardware logic needs to be allocated.